# Angular : Access variable outside of function and api call

Tags: angular

Super new to  Angular and JS, running version 10, how on earth do you get the array data after the service calls? Any tips on how to do this would be appreciated. Arrays are intact inside the calls but never outside. How can I get it so I can use the array in my html template?

```js
// PROBLEM, as noted where undefined below.

selectScript(s_id, r_id, prompts: Prompt, scripts: Script){
  this.apiService.readScript(s_id).subscribe((scripts: Script[])=>{
    this.scripts = scripts;
   // console.log(scripts); // Array OK
  });
  this.apiService.readPrompts(r_id).subscribe((prompts: Prompt[])=>{
    this.prompts = prompts;
    //console.log(prompts); // Array OK
  });
  console.log(this.scripts); // Undefined! How to get array here?
  this.ud = true;
  this.ngOnInit();
}
```

Comment: If you want process the result, just do it in the subscribe function
If you want to show the result in the view, use async pipe, here is the example
https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: The `subscribe` callback occurs after the rest of the execution, hence the undefined. This is a classic async issue.

Comment: Phix, thanks, that led me down the right route of learning to fix issue.

Comment: Hi, you should call the log inside .subscribe. It is like .then of Promises. You make an async call and whatever you pass to .then will be executed when the response comes back. A "sync" solution may be using await, but I don't recommend it.